# Centre ngx-pagination component

Tags: css

I want to centre the ngx-pagination component and remove the padding on the right-hand side. I've tried using wrapping it in a container and it doesn't work:

```
<div class="list">
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let item of collection | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p }">{{ item }}</li>
        </ul>
        <div style="text-align: center">
            <pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event"></pagination-controls>
        </div>
</div>
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e1f9hq.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How you can solve this is by wrapping a `div` around it and apply some CSS to it. `justify-content: center;` does the trick here, it will move the content of its `div` in the middle of it. You can read more about [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) and [justify-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) at MDN.

```css
.pagination {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

See [this updated StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rcg6qr) for the fix.

**Edit**

To fix the `padding-left` issue of the pagination component as seen here

[image: Padding of pagination component]

You need to add `padding-left: 0;` to the `ngx-pagination` class. One other thing you need to do is to put `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in the component's declaration (and import `ViewEncapsulation`) to let it override styles. See [updated StackBlitz for this fix](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jyemkn).

Answer (score 0):

hope this may help you.

Please try below CSS.

Note - Please add below CSS in "style.css"

```
.ngx-pagination{
  text-align: center;
 }
```